# How to make your Google sheet to read imported JSON data as a number?

Tags: json, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have imported JSON data into my sheets. I wanted to use functions such as `=STDEV` and `=AVERAGE` to the imported data but I keep getting `#div/0` error if I do. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your JSON formula into `ARRAYFORMULA` and multiply it by 1 to convert string numerals into numeric values

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTJSON(...)*1)
```

or you can just convert to numbers after the import like lets say your imported JSON stuff is in A1:A10 then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(A1:A10*1))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(VALUE(A1:A10)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this information but the first formula gives some error cause when it multiplies with the actual string literal, how can I go about multiplying specific columns or array indeices

Comment: @Rose can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: Hi @player0 how to do it within a QUERY formula to retrieve the max value row of a specific column, with a JSON output with multiple columns which some are strings columns and others are numeric columns (but outputted as string in the JSON)?
https://i.imgur.com/8RYPE0B.png

for example with this formula
`=QUERY(IMPORTJSON("myURL"),
"SELECT MAX(Col15) label MAX(Col15) ''",0)`

Comment: @player0 thanks but I'm still getting the `Col2` numbers data as string and it only return "Id" in the sample URL test below:
https://pastebin.com/GUeNgg2a

How to get it to returns `at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum`  `100` in `J1:K1` range?

Comment: @Lod try: =ARRAYFORMULA(CHOOSECOLS(LAMBDA(x, SORTN(x, 2,,INDEX(x*1,,2), ))(IMPORTJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")), 2, 3))

Comment: @Lod or: =INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(LAMBDA(x, SORTN(x, 2,,INDEX(x*1,,2), ))(IMPORTJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")), 2, 3), 2)

Comment: @player0 it works on the testing json dataset:
https://web.archive.org/web/20240125122906/https://paste.c-net.org/CaterersAmnesia 
https://web.archive.org/web/20240125123027/https://paste.c-net.org/ExtendSympathy
but on the production json dataset it returns only the 1st value and still as a string, not the max value.

For example it returns 8687.74708842 on this
https://paste.c-net.org/RestedCrime
What fix would you suggest to get the max value from Col15?

Comment: @Lod hard to tell like this. see this fx with anotations: https://i.imgur.com/lABfRvt.png plug in your json and change values next to +N() to fit your needs.

Comment: Do you mean like so with +N()? https://paste.c-net.org/CrewsScreen It only returns the column header on my end? Any further fix siggestion? thanks!

Comment: Ah it works! Thanks a lot @player0 for the awesome formula. I needed to flip the max column vs selection one as such: https://web.archive.org/web/20240125151631/https://pastebin.com/XHA1gHZH Thanks again! Be well!

Comment: @player0 just a quick new question. I looked at the LET function doc but I'm not sure how to derive this. How about getting the MIN value instead of the MAX, or the AVERAGE/MEDIAN in your formula? thanks again!

Comment: @Lod for MIN you just reverse polarity of SORTN - https://i.imgur.com/C2J7LNo.png

Comment: @player0 thanks that worked for the min. I used it as this to only get the min value: https://web.archive.org/web/20240126101309/https://pastebin.com/2qCUbfnB
I also tried to get the average using this: `=QUERY(IMPORTJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"),
 "SELECT AVG(VALUE(Col2)) label AVG(VALUE(Col2)) ''",0)` but got that error: `Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 17. Was expecting: ")" ... ` Any fix suggestion you'd recommend? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lod VALUE enclosed by AVG is syntax nonsense, hence the error. try: =INDEX(AVERAGEA(IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"),,2+N("2nd json column"))*1, "")))

Comment: @Lod =INDEX(MEDIAN(QUERY(IMPORTJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"), "select Col2 offset 1", )*1))